# How to make embedded youtube videos on transparent <div> in opera brighter?

Tags: css, youtube, cross-browser, opera, transparent

I'm trying to embed some youtube videos on transparent div
In chrome and firefox they are working ok but in opera they are very dark

opera
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIBB5.jpg

chrome/firefox
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYCC.jpg

this is my embeding code:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://youtube.com/embed/$3?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0"/></iframe>
```

I'm using IPB and this "$3" is a 3rd regular expresion match, from

```
http(?:s)?://(www.)?youtube.com/watch\?(\S+?)?v=([\d\w-_]+?)(&\S+?)?
```

wrapping div is set to opacity: 0.94;

When I set the opacity on the wrapping div to "1", embeded videos are fine.

Does anyone know how to repair this, except the "solution" with adding a javascript that will add a absolute positioned non-transparent div with the coresponding videos on top of the original ones

Answer (score 0):

Opera has a known bug regarding transparency and plugins (internally tracked as DSK-288890) which is probably causing the problem.

Does changing wmode=transparent change anything? If not, the only workaround I can think of is setting opacity to 1 for Opera.

Comment: wmode=transparent or wmode=opaque does nothing for my problem, for now I have a js that overlays a non-transparrent divs with flash content on top of the corresponding videos embeded in a transparrent div, but this soulution is not very elegant though